# How to get back spinner data

Tags: android, spinner

I filled a spinner with a query.

How can I retrieve the information that I selected? I'm having trouble with `getSelectedItem(position)`..

I have a cursor where I save the query, I fill the spinner that's no problem.   But I don't know how to assign to a string the variable I selected in the spinner.

For example

```
spinnerNAME.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
                    selEntidad = ??;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                  selEntidad ="noData";
            }
    });
```

How can I put in `selEntidad` the value of what I selected in the spinner, that I filled with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass strings to the spinner you should be able to get the corresponding string with
`(String) parent.`[getItemAtPosition(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29).

`getItemAtPosition` will always return the object the adapter uses to construct the views. So in case of a `SimpleCursorAdapter` you get the cursor at this position. You can cast the returned object to `Cursor` and then query your data. E.g. `getString(0)` if you have a string in the first column of the queried cursor.

Comment: if i put that, i receive the value SQLiteCursor@436bde18 , and not the string i want. any idea?

Comment: Do you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: yes i used a simpleCursorAdapter,  this one : 
SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,new String[] {"codGr"},    new int[] {android.R.id.text1});